# Determining a sparse matrix quotient

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am looking to divide two sparce matricies in python 2.7, essentially `k = numerator / denominator`, with the result as a sparse matrix of type `sp.csr_matrix`. I am using `scipy as sp` and `numpy as np`.

To do this, I am following linear format of taking the dot product of numerator and inverse of denominator. Both items are of format `sp.csr_matrix(([],([],[])),shape=[R,R])`.

The calculation for k itself is

```
k = sp.csr_matrix(numerator.dot(sp.linalg.inv(denominator)))
```

Doing this returns the warning:

```
SparseEfficiencyWarning: splu requires CSC matrix format
warn('splu requires CSC matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

**What does the above warning mean** in relation to determining the identity of `k` as the quotient between two sparse matrices?

**Is there a more efficient way** to generate the dot product of a sparse matrix and a sparse matrix inverse in python (the quotient of two sparse matrices)?

I had previously found [Inverting large sparse matrices with scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118177/inverting-large-sparse-matrices-with-scipy), however I wonder if this may be outdated.

Comment: Why should that 2013 answer be out dated?  Did you find any `sparse` `inv` function or discussion?

Comment: I thought it may be outdated due to updates in the scipy library since then with a member function created that I can't find. No discussions were found on the sparse inverse.

Comment: A comment indicated that a `sparse.linalg.inv` was in the works - and this is present in my version.

Comment: Yes, I am currently using `sp.linalg.inv` within the dot product, however I was returned with the warning detailed in the question and am primarily wondering if the warning could be reason for why 3 hours have passed and the terminal has not returned a result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from the 2013 answer:

```
In [409]: a=np.random.rand(3,3)
In [410]: A=sparse.csr_matrix(a)
In [411]: np.linalg.inv(a)
Out[411]: 
array([[ 26.11275413,  -4.17749006,  -9.82626551],
       [-37.22611759,   9.38404027,  13.80073216],
       [  7.59314843,  -2.04314605,  -1.58410661]])
```

The `np` inv is not `sparse-aware`:

```
In [412]: np.linalg.inv(A) 
 ....
LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional
```

With `from scipy.sparse import linalg`:

```
In [414]: linalg.inv(A).A
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py:243: SparseEfficiencyWarning: splu requires CSC matrix format
  warn('splu requires CSC matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py:161: SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve is more efficient when sparse b is in the CSC matrix format
  'is in the CSC matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)
Out[414]: 
array([[ 26.11275413,  -4.17749006,  -9.82626551],
       [-37.22611759,   9.38404027,  13.80073216],
       [  7.59314843,  -2.04314605,  -1.58410661]])
```

So use the `csc` format instead of `csr`:

```
In [415]: A1=sparse.csc_matrix(a)
In [416]: linalg.inv(A1).A
Out[416]: 
array([[ 26.11275413,  -4.17749006,  -9.82626551],
       [-37.22611759,   9.38404027,  13.80073216],
       [  7.59314843,  -2.04314605,  -1.58410661]])
```

Same thing, but without the sparsity warning.  Without getting into details, the `inv` must be using a method that iterates on columns rather than rows.  It does  `spsolve(A, I)`  (`I` is a sparse `eye` matrix).

Comment: Great, thanks. Could you detail the primary difference between use of `csc` versus `csr`? I was primarily using `csr` as thats the format in which the legacy code is held as.

Comment: `csc` is basically the transpose of `csr`.  In fact `M.T` where `M` is `csr`, is `csc` with the same data and pointers.  Look at their `data`, `indices` and `indptr` attributes.

Comment: Extremely helpful - I could not quickly identify the distinction from the `scipy` documentation. Thank you!