# Minimize memory overhead in sparse matrix inverse

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

As pretense, I am continuing development in Python 2.7 from a prior question: [Determining a sparse matrix quotient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050947/determining-a-sparse-matrix-quotient)

### My existing code:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp

k = sp.csr_matrix(([], ([],[])),shape=[R,R])

denom = sp.csc_matrix(denominator)
halfeq = sp.linalg.inv(denom)
k = numerator.dot(halfeq)
```

I was successful in calculating for the base `k` and `denom`. Python continued attempting calculation on `halfeq`. The process sat in limbo for aproximately 2 hours before returning an error

### Error Statement:

```
Not enough memory to perform factorization.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<myfilename.py>", line 111, in <module>
    halfeq = sp.linalg.inv(denom)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py", line 61, in inv Ainv = spsolve(A, I)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py", line 151, in spsolve Afactsolve = factorized(A)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py", line 366, in factorized return splu(A).solve
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py", line 242, in splu ilu=False, options=_options)
MemoryError
```

From the [scipy/smemory.c sourcecode](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/SuperLU/SRC/smemory.c), the initial statement from the error is found on line 256. I am unable to further analyze the memory defs to determine how to best reallocate memory usage sufficient for execution.

For reference,

`numerator` has `shape: (552297, 552297)` with `stored elements: 301067607` calculated as `sp.csr_matrix(A.T.dot(Ap))`

`denominator` has `shape: (552297, 552297)` with `stored elements: 170837213` calculated as `sp.csr_matrix(A.T.dot(A))`

**EDIT**: I've found [a related question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3c0m7b/what_is_the_most_precise_way_to_invert_large/), but cannot determine how I would change my equation from `numerator * inv(denominator) = k`

Comment: Are you sure the `k` you want to calculate is sparse? (Or the `halfeq`?)

Answer (score 1):

No need to 'preallocate' `k`; this isn't a compiled language.  Not that this is costing anything.

```
k = sp.csr_matrix(([], ([],[])),shape=[R,R])
```

I need to double check this, but I think the `dot/inv` can be replaced by one call to `spsolve`.  Remember in the other question I noted that `inv` is `spsolve(A, I)`;

```
denom = sp.csc_matrix(denominator)
#halfeq = sp.linalg.inv(denom)
#k = numerator.dot(halfeq)
k = sp.linalg.spsolve(denom, numerator)
```

That said, it looks like the problem is in the `inv` part, the `factorized(denom)`.  While your arrays are sparse, (denom density is 0.00056), they still have a large number of values.

Maybe it would help to step back and look at:

```
num = A.T.dot(Ap)
den = A.T.dot(A)
k = solve(den, num)
```

In other words, review the matrix algebra.

```
(A'*Ap)/(A'*A)
```

I'm little rusty on this.  Can we reduce this?  Can we partition?

Just throwing great big arrays together, even if they are sparse, isn't working.

How about providing small `A` and `Ap` arrays that we can use for testing?  I'm not interested in testing memory limits, but I'd like to experiment with different calculation methods.

The sparse linalg module has a number of iterative solvers.  I have no idea whether their memory use is greater or less.

Comment: I am on travel for remainder of the week, but if successful with the VPN later on I'll try to pull back the data for A and Ap (though it is worth noting that Ap is a subset of A)